# Set custom headers to ajax call in Backbone.model with two ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have a backbone model.

```
var mymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 url: '/url'
});

var newmodel = new mymodel();

newmodel.fetch({
    beforeSend: sendheader, //I want to set a header here!
    success: function() {
       //do something here
    }
    error: function() {
      //do something else here
    }

});
```

Here is a method to set header

```
//This works
sendheader = function(xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader("ToKEN-ID", token);
}
```

**The problem:**

I want to get token from another ajax call

```
sendheader = function(xhr) {
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/gettoken',
     success:function(data) { 
       xhr.setRequestHeader("ToKEN-ID", token);
     }
   });
 }
```

This doesnot work because xhr object has been overwritten maybe? it seems like after i make another ajax call I lose xhr object? How can I preserve XHR object for second ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendheader` is a function and jQuery is asynchronous.

So `sendheader` will call the ajax `get` and without waiting for it's return it will execute next statement.

So `newModel.fetch` would be called without setting `xhr`. - *You cannot do it this way.*

**Alternative**

Get the token first and in the success method of it, use your `newModel.fetch`

Ex.

```
sendheader = function(xhr) {
   var thisModel = this;
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/gettoken',
     success:function(data) { 
       thisModel.trigger('tokengot',data);
     }
   });
 }
```

and

```
var mymodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 url: '/url'
});

var newmodel = new mymodel();

newmodel.on('tokengot',function(token){    

newmodel.fetch({
    beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader("ToKEN-ID", token);}, //token and xhr variable name may be inaccuate in my code
    success: function() {
       //do something here
    }
    error: function() {
      //do something else here
    }

});
}
newmodel.sendheader() // i believe send header is function of this model itself
```